# How can i replace Varien Library for magento with new one?

Tags: magento

I want to download & replace whole "Lib_Varien" or  "varien library" by new varien library.How can i do this? or From where can i download Varien Library for magento version?
Is replacement will create any disturbances..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's known as upgrading. You go to a new version of Magento. Too many things change for a modular change of the Varien Library like this to be possible.